# Using limits to find the range

Tags: calculus, limits

Say a function is continuous everywhere. Could one determine the range of this continuous function by taking the limit as $x$ approaches $0$, $\infty$ and $-\infty$? My guess is yes. I would, however, like a confirmation.

Comment: What do you mean exactly with range? You want to find out if $f(x)$ is limited and if yes what the max and min are? Or you mean something else?

Comment: If it is a Real-valued function maybe, but once your range is $\mathbb R^n$ , that does not work any more.

Comment: By range, I mean all the values of y in y=f(x). Aso, f(x) is everywhere defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No; not always; the max/min value may be reached at some point other than $0, +\infty, -\infty$. e.g., take a parabola that is not centered at $0$, say $y=(x-2)^2$ ; then$f(0)=4; "f(\infty)=f(-\infty)"=\infty$ , but , at $x=2$, you get the value $0$ , i.e., $y(2)=(2-2)^2=0$ . Still, if you know the Max/Sup or Min/Inf values, you may be able to.

NOTE that I'm using quotes when I write $f(\infty), f(-\infty)$.

Answer (score 0):

Consider 
$$ f(x)=\frac{cx}{x^2+1}.$$
You have $f(0)=\lim{x\to\pm\infty}=0$ and yest the range depends on $c$ (and it is $[-\frac{|c|}2,\frac{|c|}2]$)

Comment: Yes, this is actually obvious. Thank you